# search suggestions and elasticsearch multi-field

Tags: elasticsearch

If I'm trying to use the ES match_phrase_prefix [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-match-query.html) query for for search suggestions, but I'd like to do with with multi-fields... can it be done? I'm trying to find this answer in the docs but can't seem to find it.

Comment: For multi-field searching you need to set the analyzer while creating it's type. Can't understand ? reply.

Comment: @AbdullaAlSun, so in the mapping, I should set analyzers for index and search - is that what your saying?

Comment: For every field you want to search with match_phrase_prefix you need to set analyzers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
"query":{
        "bool":{
              "should":[
                      {"match_phrase_prefix":{"field1":"search"}}
                      {"match_phrase_prefix":{"field2":"search"}},
                      {"match_phrase_prefix":{"field3":"search"}}
               ]
         }
},
```